# Вставить код с помощью тернарного оператора

Tags: php

```
$temp = '
            <div class="wosummnazv"><img src="'.
            if($vname === "Qiwi"){echo "/wp-content/uploads/Qiwi.png"}
            .'"/>'. $vname .' '. $vtype .'</div>
    </div>      
    ';
```

Как я могу вставить код php (`if($vname === "Qiwi"){echo "/wp-content/uploads/Qiwi.png"}`) внутрь , с помощью тернарного оператора . . 
Нашел способ вместо . использовать ;, но не сработало

Comment: не надо там внутрь ничего вставлять, предварительно сделайте переменную с нужным значением, хоть тернарным оператором, хоть любым другим,  а затем вставьте в строку эту как vname и vtype

Comment: @teran мне нужно вставить условие, его возможно поместить в переменнную?

Comment: `$x = $vname == 'Qiwi' ? "/img/qiwi.jpg" : "not-qiwi.jpg"`  => `<img src="$x">`

Comment: можете и туда вставить `"<img src='". ( $vname == "qiwi" ? "qiwi.jpg" : "not-qiwi.jpg") . "'/>"`, но такое читать сложнее

Comment: @teran помогло, спасибо! не подскажете как сделать условие типа elseif. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предварительно определите переменную, в которой вычислите название нужной картинки, а оптом вставьте в разметку.

```
$src = ($vname == "Qiwi") ? "Qiwi.png" :  "not-Qiwi.jpg";
$temp = "<div class='wosummnazv'><img src='/wp-content/uploads/$src'/>$vname $vtype</div></div>";
```

Можете и прямо в разметку вставить тернарный оператор, но это будет смотреться громоздко.

> не подскажете как сделать условие типа `elseif`

Если требуется несколько вариантов условий, то используйте `switch` или массив

```
switch($vname){
   case 'Qiwi': $src = "qiwi.jpg"; break;
   case 'Something': $src = "some_image.png"; break;
   default: $src = "image_not_found.jpg"; break;
}
```

либо

```
$images = ['Qiwi' => "qiwi.jpg", 'Something' => "some_image.png", ....];
$src = $images[$vname];
```

Упомянутый else-if, конечно, никто не запрещает использовать, наравне со `switch`.

ну или возможно, если все картинки назвать соответственно, то просто

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/$vname.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!